# Azure AD accessToken version is different from acceptAcessTokenVersion ios

Tags: ios, azure, access-token, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

My iOS app is using AD authentication using [MSAL iOS Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) for end points v2.0 to get id_token and accessToken for scope https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation and login is successful, received id_token and accessToken.

When i decode both in jwt.io to check version, there is version mismatch. It is correct for id_token i.e 2.0 but for accessToken it's still as v1.0.

Have also set accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 in manifest [as mentioned here in doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference)
still there is mismatch in version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the access token is for Azure Storage.
It has defined that it wants v1 tokens.
So you get a v1 token.

The setting only affects id tokens and access tokens meant for your app.

You should not be looking inside access tokens that are not meant for your app.
You just send it in the Authorization header to the API and it'll check it.